# One database vs Multiple database in SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a sql server running on my machine.It contains 10 data base file.
 say

1. a
2. b

....

10. z

so my question is 10 or more database or 1 single database is best for sql server .Does more database cause more performance issue on single server machine? what is recommended?

Comment: Store data in a single table.  If you have multiple tables, put them in the same database.  Databases are designed to handle large amounts of data.

Comment: Agreed .BUT my product server contains 10 database file ? Does sql server  cause any issue ?? or single database with 10 schema is best for sql server and its performance?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info. What kind of databases are these? Complex/simple schemas, same/different schema, size? Without any context it's hard to speculate on performance scenario. Usually you have 10 databases if you need 10 and only one if your database relational schema is contained inside of one database...

Comment: SIMPLE DATABASE....@Robert Koritnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly Common issue is for poor database design

The causes for performance problems can be various, but the most common are a poorly designed database, incorrectly configured system, insufficient disk space or other system resources, excessive query compilation and recompilation, bad execution plans due to missing or outdated statistics, and queries or stored procedures that have long execution times due to improper design
Memory bottlenecks are caused by limitations in available memory and memory pressure caused by SQL Server, system, or other application activity. Poor indexing requires table scans which in case of large tables means that a large number of rows is read from disk and handled in memory
Network bottlenecks are caused by overload on a server or network, so the data cannot flow as expected
I/O issues can be caused by slow hardware used, bad storage solution design, and configuration. Besides hardware components, such as disk types, disk array type, and RAID configuration that affect I/O performance, unnecessary requests made by a database also affect I/O traffic. Frequent index scans, inefficient queries, and out of date statistics can also cause I/O workload and bottlenecks
- See more at: http://www.sqlshack.com/dba-guide-sql-server-performance-troubleshooting-part-1-problems-performance-metrics/#sthash.QrzEyKbz.dpuf

Multiple Database is not a problem for performance.
you can see these links. I think it will help you about understanding performance tuning :D

Answer (score 1):

You may think like:

"Using multiple databases helps like they are outer index and it can be helpfull for search times.

Think like that, when searching begins, your database server takes your query it will go the firstly to your table and it will execute query on that table and which helps for querying time because datas on other tables will not be looked only your table index will be looked at tables table. :)

In same manner when you group your tables on different dbs query will begin to look just table index of that table on tables table and because there will be less table in that table finding your tables table id will going to complete in less time. :) "

But that is not correct! If you dont have millions of tables it will not going to impact because datastructures used on dbs mostly acces data in O(log(n)) and that means that if(Big if) accesing in 1,000,000 input takes 6 step complete then 100,000 will take 5 step and 1,000 will take 3. As you can see it not makes difference.

On the other hand using 2 db guarantees that it has to be at least 2 connections and connections are expensive things and that is why connection pools are exist.